HTML report when running locust on EKS pods
I have a setup where, I have to create a Kubernetes namespace and run locust (main + worker) nodes in headless mode in that namespace for each API under test. This enables me to run multiple tests at the same time.
When I give it the --html option on the main node I don't see the html reports being generated.
Is there a reason why I cannot find the HTML report?
When I run the same code locally I can see the report generated but I want to do it on EKS pods.
I also trigger a resource cleanup at the end of the test, so I want to generate the html reports and save it to S3 as well, I know I can do it in the @events.test_stop.add_listener annotated method.
Running locally it creates the html report when run with --html option but the same doesn't work when running locust in headless mode on EKS.
